# Как правильно использовать re.sub?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re, замена

Задание следующее: заменить 4 пробела перед словом на 8 пробелов перед словом, при этом нужно использовать регулярные выражения.

Хочу заменить одно регулярное выражение (`r'(\s{4})(\w+):'`) на другое (`r'(\s{8})(\w+):("\w+"),'`).

Почему при использовании регулярки

```
re.sub(r'(\s{4})(\w+):', r'(\s{8})(\w+):("\w+"),', stroka)
```

второй аргумент не считывается, то есть выводит ошибку?

Comment: Слова "выводит ошибку" должны сопровождаться текстом ошибки. Перед этим убедись, что ты этот текст ошибки прочитал и постарался понять, в чем причина. Возможно, вопрос после этого станет не нужен. Как правильно использовать re.sub написано в документации и сотне примеров.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6BMBZt/1

Comment: @tocic там ещё ":"

Comment: @Виктор может быть. Но ":" после слова не влияет на "заменить 4 пробела перед словом на 8 пробелов перед словом".

Comment: Цифры - это не слово

Answer (score -1):

код:

```
stroka = 'w    word1:    word2'
print(stroka)
result = re.sub(r'(\s{4}(\w+):)', r'        \2,', stroka)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
w    word1:    word2
w        word1,    word2

w    word1:    word2: word3
w        word1,        word2, word3
```

Comment: Нигде не сказано, что заменить нужно только в одном месте.

Comment: А кто сказал, что заменит только в одном месте?

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы уже замучали выставляя не разобравшись в вопросе, отрицательные оценки ответам

Comment: Ну вы же и сказали  В ответе все написано. Кроме того, я проверил. Так что сначала научитесь писать хороший код, а не жаловаться на оценки.

Comment: Хорошо, напишите как должно быть лучше, хочется перенять опыт

Comment: Я не пишу ответы тем, кто не осилил сообщение об ошибке, и вам советую не утруждаться. Товарищ, похоже, в ответе и не очень заинтересован, поскольку до сих пор не объявился.